# Mobile alternative for dojo select widget

Tags: mobile, dojo, dojox.mobile

I am developing a mobile app using dojo mobile. I need functionality similar to dijit.form.Select However I have not been able to locate mobile equivalent for the same.

If such a widget is not available off the shelf, is there any way I can achieve the required functionality using dojo mobile module.